# Error while using function name as a variable in Pycharm, Python, Django: local variable 'processed' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, variables, pycharm

I use Pycharm Professional 2019.2, Python 3.7.4, Django 2.2.5.
As I know, function names are global variables in modules. But I have a function that denies that.

```
def processed(request):
    if request.method == 'post':
        text = request.post['text']
        processed = text.upper()
    return HttpResponse(processed)
```

The browser shows the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /process/
local variable 'processed' referenced before assignment
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/process/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'processed' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: 1. avoid naming functions and variables the same thing. 2. here you do not define `processed` when your request is _not_ a POST.  (hint: put `processed = None` above your if statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to do:

```
def processed(request):
    # Do not use the function name as the parameter name.
    ret = processed

    # It should be 'POST', not 'post'.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # It should be 'POST', not 'post'.
        text = request.POST['text']
        ret = text.upper()

    return HttpResponse(ret)
```

Comment: then it is already defined as function reference error here is `UnboundError` answer lies in python internals

Comment: Please try to run the code that you have provided. It will work just fine. It won't throw `UnboundError` error.

Comment: it is raising the error the second implementation `UnboundLocalError`